# knockout can't delete newly added item to observableArray using FireFox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, knockout.js, cross-browser

I have a small page which list data coming  Knockout array and with every item I have delete link. Clicking on delete link item next to link is deleted from array but I can't delete newly added item.

JSFiddler: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yawer/SK78e/1/)

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: tagToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<button data-bind="click: addTag">+ Add</button>
<div data-bind="foreach: tags">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>    
    <a href="#" class="deleteItm">Delete </a>       
</div>
```

Here is JS code:

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "abc" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "def" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "ghi" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "jkl" }
];

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    //data
    self.tags = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.tagToAdd = ko.observable();

    //behaviour
    self.addTag = function () {
        self.tags.push({ Name: self.tagToAdd() });
        self.tagToAdd("");
    };
};


$(function () {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $(".deleteItm").on("click", function () {
        var itmToRemove = ko.dataFor(this);
        console.log(itmToRemove);
        vm.tags.remove(itmToRemove);

        ko.applyBindings(vm);


    });
```

**Question / Issue :**
        I need to make this code deleting newly (dynamically)  added items. If I add a new item and delte it do not work but delete items coming from JS

**Edit:**
I just have checked it do not work just in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to not use jQuery itself but to use knockout to remove the item.

```
self.deleteItem = function(item) {
  self.tags.remove(item)
};

<a href="#" class="deleteItm" data-bind="click: $root.deleteItem">Delete </a>
```

Comment: thanks it worked but since i m learning Knockout, I just want to ask why my delete code is not working in FF, can you please suggest ? In general your code is fine and it worked for me.

Comment: You shouldn't be applying bindings twice. You only ever do that once. The problem is when you add an item, it won't be attaching the remove click event to the new item.

Comment: It's just easier to not worry about jquery and just use knockout. If you mix both together, your code will get messy and you'll have issues like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for binding event to dynamically added DOM:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on("click",'.deleteItm', function () {
    var itmToRemove = ko.dataFor(this);
    console.log(itmToRemove);
    vm.tags.remove(itmToRemove);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```